# "Hin" und "her": Von wessen Standpunkt?

Tags: grammar, prefix

Wenn jemand  Deutsch zu lernen anfängt, erklärt man ihm den Unterschied zwischen *hin-* und *her-* :

> Sitze ich in meinem Büro, so rufe ich *Kommen sie bitte herein!*
>   Stehe ich aber außerhalb des Büros, so sage ich *Gehen sie bitte hinein!*

Das ist klar, aber wie soll man allgemein entscheiden, von welchem Standpunkt die Lage betrachtet wird?
Ein Beispiel [von unserer  Site](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5807/194):

> *Der Kellner beugte sich zu dem Gast herab*.

Hier scheint der Erzähler den Standpunkt des Gastes anzunehmen.
Könnte man auch den des Kellners annehmen:

> *Der Kellner beugte sich zu dem Gast hinab*?

Ich stelle mir auch eine ähnliche Frage für feste Ausdrücke, wie zum Beispiel in *Sie ist auf ihn reingefallen*.
Man kann solche Ausdrücke zwar nicht ändern, aber was ist deren historische Erklärung?

Comment: Yes, you could just as easily see things from the waiter's point of view, i.e., `hinab`.

Comment: Ach,interessant: danke, Eugene!

Comment: ... and as to why it is _Sie ist auf ihn 'reingefallen_ and not _Sie ist auf ihn 'neingefallen_, my guess would be that the latter just does not roll off the tongue as easily!

Answer (score 4):

> Sitze ich in meinem Büro, so rufe ich: "Kommen sie bitte herein!".
>   Stehe ich aber außerhalb des Büros, so sage ich: "Gehen sie bitte hinein!".
>   <sub>It is direct speech and requires quotes and a colon</sub>

In these cases, the point of view is quite clear and the prefixes `hin-` and `her-` cannot be exchanged.

> Der Kellner beugte sich zu dem Gast herab.

Here indeed the subject is the waiter, but it's not the waiters point of view nor the guests. This is why in principle **both** is possible.

Regardless of this, use `her-` in case of doubt. Its more hardly noticed than a misplaced `hin-`

Comment: Wie Eugene Seidel mit dem Beispiel zur Antwort von alexraasch schon angedeutet hat, präjudiziert eine vorangestellte direkte Rede den Erzählstandpunkt. Und dieser ist nicht automatisch mit dem Subjekt des folgenden Satzes identisch. Deshalb ist es logischer zu sagen: "Der Kellner beugte sich zum Gast herab", wenn letzterer vorher gesprochen hat und wir auch danach das Geschehen aus der Sicht des Gastes betrachten, aber "der Kellner beugte sich zum Gast hinunter und entfaltete für ihn die Serviette", z.B. nachdem er vorher einen anderen Tisch bedient hatte.

Answer (score 2):

Das Problem ist, dass selbst viele deutsche Muttersprachler nicht richtig zwischen "hin" und "her" unterscheiden. "Der Kellner beugte sich zu dem Gast herab" ist nicht richtig. Es muss "hinab" heißen. Aber es gibt auch feststehende Redewendungen, die man einfach hinnehmen muss. "Jemand fällt auf jemanden rein" ist so eine Redewendung. Woher das historisch kommt, weiß ich nicht.

Also what Eugene said about things rolling off the tongue more easily. That's also true and sometimes influences grammar.

Comment: "Herr Ober!" Der Kellner beugte sich zu dem Gast herab. "Bringen Sie uns noch zwei Kaffee, bitte." Are you saying that it has to be `hinab` because the waiter is the subject of the second sentence? That's plausible. But I also find it plausible that `herab` instead of `hinab` shifts focus to the guest, which is a legitimate thing to do IMO.

Comment: Yes, it's plausible somehow that's why many use it. If you say "herab", no one will probably think it's wrong and it won't sound odd to anyone. But it's like saying "Ich gehe dahin". You can't replace that by "Ich gehe daher." (You can but it means something different.) In English, you would say "The waiter was leaning towards the guest." But you can't replace "towards" here with something like "fromwards". In English it's more obvious.

Maybe it helps to remember that "hin" points in a direction whereas "her" refers to a source or an origin.

Comment: And yes, the reason is that waiter is the subject.

Comment: So would you also call `Rapunzel, lass dein Haar herunter!` wrong?

Comment: Wenn ich das Objekt "Gast" durch das Objekt "mich" ersetze, kann "herab" doch nicht falsch sein, oder doch? @EugeneSeidel: If there is a rule about the subject, it could be that sentences with the verb in the imperative are an exception :)

Comment: @alexraasch: Does that mean, according to your opinion, example sentences from Duden such as ["der Raubvogel stieß plötzlich auf das Feld herab"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herabstoszen), ["er sah vom Balkon zu uns herunter"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/heruntersehen#b2-Bedeutung-1), ["er ist die Treppe heruntergefallen"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herunterfallen#b2-Bedeutung-a), or ["die Mutter beugt sich zu ihrem Kind herunter"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herunterbeugen) are all wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Wie @Eugene Seidel mit dem Beispiel zur Antwort von @alexraasch schon angedeutet hat, präjudiziert eine vorangestellte direkte Rede den Erzählstandpunkt. Und dieser ist nicht automatisch mit dem Subjekt des folgenden Satzes identisch. Deshalb ist es logischer zu sagen: "Der Kellner beugte sich zum Gast herab", wenn Letzterer vorher gesprochen hat und wir auch danach das Geschehen aus der Sicht des Gastes betrachten, aber "der Kellner beugte sich zum Gast hinunter und entfaltete für ihn die Serviette", z. B. nachdem er vorher einen anderen Tisch bedient hatte. Man kann damit natürlich auch sehr gut die Erzählperspektive steuern – oder durcheinanderbringen, wenn man damit nicht genau umgehen kann.

Feststehende Wendungen geben deshalb Auskunft darüber, aus welcher Perspektive sie ursprünglich geprägt wurden. Man hat oft den Eindruck, dass diese Perspektive sich im Verlauf des Gebrauchs einer Wendung ändert. "Hereinfallen" gibt die Sicht dessen wieder, der die Falle gestellt hat, was allerdings die Anwesenheit des Fallenstellers in der Falle voraussetzt: "Du bist auf mich hereingefallen!" Warum sollte jemand "aus sich herausgehen" wollen? Bedeutet das "heraus" in "herausgeben", dass der Herausgeber in Form eines Buches wieder zurückgibt, was ihm zuvor in Form von Manuskripten anvertraut wurde? Bei "sich zu viel herausnehmen" ist die Perspektive wiederum sehr klar. Man muss wohl in jedem einzelnen Fall Herkunft und Bedeutungswandel genau prüfen.