# Hinfallen, hinunterfallen vs. herunterfallen

Tags: word-usage, verb

Diese Frage wurde von einer Frage inspiriert, die ich vor kurzem zu den Verben *fallen* und *stürzen* gestellt habe.

Jemand hat erwähnt, dass in einem gewissen Zusammenhang *herunterfallen* besser passt als *hinfallen*.  Was genau ist der Unterschied zwischen *hin-* und *herunter-* bei diesen Worten, die "fall down" heißen?  Ich weiß z.B., dass man für "lay (something) down" *hinlegen* und nicht *herunterlegen* sagt.

Danke! ....und bitte zögert nicht meine Grammatik (usw.) in dieser Frage zu verbessern!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5822/hin-und-her-von-wessen-standpunkt/5826#5826

Comment: As explained by user Alex Raasch in his Answer to the Question of which this one is a duplicate, the rules of grammar and logic are sometimes flouted by Germans. Specifically they say _herab_ when they should say _hinab_ because the subject's point of view should dictate the choice. [continued]

Comment: [cont'd] Essentially the same applies to _hinunter_ and _herunter_: Wiktionary, quoting Bastian Sick, [says](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/herunter#cite_note-2): "Diese Unterscheidung ist nicht mehr in allen Regionen zu finden: In der Umgangssprache in Norddeutschland sagt man immer _runter_. Anders ist dies in Süddeutschland, wo man zwischen den umgangssprachlichen Formen _’runter_ (=herunter) und _’nunter_ (=hinunter) differenziert." I would expect that even in south Germany, _runter_ will subsume both forms: _Er ist runtergefallen_ (regardless of whether speaker's POV is top or bottom).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Herunterfallen* bedeutet einfach, daß¹ etwas oder jemand von einer höheren Position nach unten fällt:

> Der Maler ist von der Leiter heruntergefallen.
>
> Das Buch ist vom Tisch heruntergefallen.
>
> Wo kommt denn der Stuhl her? – Er muß¹ wohl vom Balkon heruntergefallen sein.

Weil ein Fall ja nun meistens nach unten führt, kann man das *herunter-* auch oft weglassen und einfach nur *fallen* sagen.

*Hinfallen* wird im Normalfall nur für Menschen verwendet; vielleicht auch noch für (zweibeinige) Roboter. Entscheidend ist, daß¹ dabei jemand *das Gleichgewicht verliert* und daraufhin umfällt (ganz oder sich beispielsweise auf die Hände oder Knie stützen muß¹; jedenfalls nicht mehr die normale, aufrechte Haltung auf zwei Beinen hat).

> Sie ist über einen Stein gestolpert und hingefallen.
>
> Es ist glatt, paß¹ auf, daß¹ du nicht hinfällst!

Im übertragenen Sinn kann *hinfallen* auch „einen Mißerfolg¹ erleiden“ bedeuten, wobei *auf die Nase fallen* bzw. *auf die Schnauze fallen* hierfür allerdings deutlich häufiger ist (umgangssprachlich).

Für Gegenstände benutzt man in vergleichbaren Fällen *umfallen*:

> Durch die Böe ist das Fahrrad umgefallen.
>
> Der Baum hat die Weißfäule und wird eines Tages umfallen.

---

¹ In neuer Rechtschreibung jeweils mit *ss* statt *ß*.

Comment: Mißerfolg *(neue Rechtschreibung: Misserfolg)* :-)

Comment: Mit dem "Im übertragenen Sinn..." bin ich nicht so ganz einverstanden. Üblicherweise würde man da nicht von *hinfallen*, sondern von *auf die Nase/Schnauze fallen* sprechen und das ist eher umgangssprachlich verwendet.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: Bezgl. ß/ss, ich hatte es ursprünglich nur in den Beispielsätzen markiert, insofern war es Absicht, daß der Hinweis bei _Mißerfolg_ fehlte. Ich habe das noch einmal bearbeitet und jetzt durchgehend mit einer Fußnote angemerkt. – Bezgl. übertragene Bedeutung: Richtig, ich habe jetzt eingebaut, daß man sehr viel häufiger auf die Nase fällt als einfach nur hin. ;-) Es gibt aber die beliebte Redewendung „Hinfallen darf man, man muß nur wieder aufstehen“ (viele Varianten) und etwa hier [geschäftlich hingefallen](http://f3.webmart.de/f.cfm?id=2962376&r=threadview&t=3381090&pg=1).

Comment: Hinfallen nur für Menschen? Mir ist das Glas hingefallen.

Comment: Warum nutzt du die alte Rechtschreibung? Demnach müsste die Aussprache von `daß` lang sein, analog zu Spaß, und `Mißerfolg` wird wie `Mieserfolg` ausgesprochen - weil vor einem einzelnen Konsonanten immer ein langes Vokal steht.

Answer (score 5):

Ohne es belegen zu können, würde ich sagen herunterfallen bedeutet, dass der Auflagepunkt sich nach dem Fallen unterhalb des Niveaus befindet welches es vor dem Fall hatte, während er beim Hinfallen auf oder oberhalb dieses Niveaus bleibt.

Comment: also man fällt hin, wenn man beim Rennen über etwas stolpert, weil er auf dem gleichen Niveau (auf dem Boden) bleibt?  aber man fällt vom Ast eines Baumes herunter?

Comment: So war es gemeint .

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde sagen, es kommt noch darauf an, wo sich der Sprecher befindet.
Um chirlus Beispiel zu verwenden:

> Der Maler ist von der Leiter heruntergefallen.

Das würden Leute sagen, die unten stehen und die Situation beobachten. Der Kollege des Malers, der sich immer noch oben auf der Leiter befindet (lassen wir mal sicherheitsrelevante Bedenken weg, dass zwei Leute auf einer Leiter arbeiten:) ), würde sagen:

> Mein Kollege ist von der Leiter hinuntergefallen.

Ebenso dieses Beispiel:

> Wo kommt denn der Stuhl her? – Er muss wohl vom Balkon heruntergefallen sein.

Das würden die Leute sagen, auf deren Balkon der Stuhl von einem höheren Balkon *herunter* gefallen ist. Die Leute, die auf dem Balkon sind, von dem der Stuhl *hinunter* gefallen ist, würden sagen:

> Wo ist denn unser Stuhl hin? – Er muss wohl auf den Balkon (unter uns) hinuntergefallen sein.

Immer wenn "hin" im Spiel ist, wird etwas vom Sprecher weg, und bei "her" zum Sprecher ran bewegt. (Hier hätte auch "zum Sprecher hin bewegt" gepasst, aber das hätte für Verwirrung gesorgt.)

Hier noch ein paar Beispiele:

> "**Geh** mal da drüben **hin**!"
>
> "**Komm** mal **her**!"
>
> "Bring mir bitte das Buch **herunter**." (das Buch kommt zu mir)
>
> "Ich bringe dir jetzt das Buch **hinunter**." (das Buch geht von mir weg)
>
> "Siehst du die Mauer da? Ich werfe den Ball **hinüber**!"
>
> "Schau mal, da wirft jemand einen Ball **herüber**!" (Die Leute auf der anderen Seite der Mauer)

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass mir jemals in dem Kontext ein Anwendungsunterschied zwischen *hin* und *her* aufgefallen wäre. Ich bin mir nicht mal sicher, ob in meiner Region (Westen) *hin* überhaupt verwendet wird (Kontext Abwärtsbewegung). Ich würde immer das Buch herunterbringen. Und stehe ich noch auf der Leiter, wäre der Kollege in meinen Augen schlicht heruntergefallen.

Comment: @Em1 Ich gebe zu, dass "hinuntergefallen" irgendwie komisch klingt. Eventuell hat sich "heruntergefallen" einfach durchgesetzt. Ich habe hier noch einen Link gefunden, wo sich der Zwiebelfisch mit genau dem Thema beschäftigt: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-nach-oben-hinauf-und-von-oben-herunter-a-341697.html