# What does "hinschauen" mean?

Tags: word-usage

I understand that *"schauen"* means *to look* but I have difficulties to understand *"hinschauen"* in this context

> Ich habe mich auf den ersten Blick verliebt. Ich hätte zweimal hinschauen sollen.

Answer (score 8):

„hinschauen“ is the opposite of „wegschauen“, to look away. It means to look at something and pay attention to it.  Hence

> Ich hätte zweimal hinschauen sollen.

means that the speaker should have had a second look, considered things more carefully (so that they might have seen flaws they did not see).

Answer (score 4):

`hin` and `her` give a direction, in this case of the sight ([see also](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7794/how-to-use-the-hin-and-her-prefixes)) and they come with the questions `wohin?` and `woher?`

> Ich habe zu ihm hingeschaut und er hat zu mir hergeschaut.
>   *Wohin hast du geschaut? Zu ihm hin.*

**In your example** the question `Wohin?` is not explicitly answered, thus **it has a figurative sense**,  meaning something like

> I should have paid more attention to what I was doing

Comment: I would have never figured out the special connotation of `hin` in `hinschauen` without looking it up, since literally translated it simply means `look to(ward)`

Comment: Also, since `herschauen` isn't a word, I think too much comparison with the usual usage of `hin` and `her` could be misleading

Answer (score 0):

> Ich habe mich auf den ersten Blick verliebt. Ich hätte zweimal
>   **hin**-schauen sollen.

Translation

I fell in love with you at first sight. I should have looked **at** you twice.

Or more roughly:

I fell in love with you when I first looked at you. I should have looked at you twice. / I should have looked you a second time. (maybe then I'd not be in love with you)

Comment: I'd explain "hin" by emphasising that you should *again*, that is after looking away for a while.