# When are "gehen" and ""hingehen" most appropriately used?

Tags: expression

What is the main difference in the way they are used ?

Comment: In what way did a dictionary not help you?

Comment: En passant, I can refer to this question: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7794/how-to-use-the-hin-and-her-prefixes

Comment: @chirlu I have landed here because my dictionary does not explain it either.

Answer (score 4):

**Gehen** is more general (**to go** or **to walk** maybe) - **Hingehen** is used more often, if you mean, that somebody is going to a specific place or destination (**to go to** would be a good translation).